Trying to edit TODO state with org-element results in "DONE TODO ..."
I'm toying a bit with org-element in order to fully understand how to use it.
Here is the code
(defun my--get-org-parse-tree (file-path)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file-path)
    (org-element-parse-buffer)))


(defun my--org-mark-hl-as-done (headline)
  (org-element-put-property headline :todo-keyword "DONE"))

(defun my-org-make-all-done (path)
  (let* ((org-ast (my--get-org-parse-tree path)))
    (org-element-map org-ast 'headline (lambda (hl)
                                         (my--org-mark-hl-as-done hl)))
    (let ((new-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*Result*")))
           (with-current-buffer new-buffer
             (insert (org-element-interpret-data org-ast)))
           (switch-to-buffer new-buffer))))

Here is the sample .org file:
* TODO Hello
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       3119ada6-29ba-4f58-8936-f4cc1dd16f21
:END:
Hello world!
* My math homeworks
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       ac2f6510-8dfb-4e43-8565-0aa0c4b7f3e9
:END:
+ 2+2 = ?
+ 5+2 = ?
* My shopping list
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       9f71fa91-ba63-4cb3-b7a2-d58bbce34beb
:END:
+ Apples
+ Tomatoes
+ Banana

Trying to run my-org-make-all-done against it results in:
* DONE TODO Hello
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       3119ada6-29ba-4f58-8936-f4cc1dd16f21
:END:
Hello world!
* DONE My math homeworks
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       ac2f6510-8dfb-4e43-8565-0aa0c4b7f3e9
:END:
- 2+2 = ?
- 5+2 = ?
* DONE My shopping list
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       9f71fa91-ba63-4cb3-b7a2-d58bbce34beb
:END:
- Apples
- Tomatoes
- Banana

Why does the first headline have "DONE TODO"? It appears that it kind of detects "TODO" as part of the title. Am I misusing org-element?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

@Drew Ouch. Sorry!

When you read in the contents of the file into a temp buffer in my--get-org-parse-tree, the temp buffer is in fundamental mode, so the headline is interpreted literally. So, yes, you are misusing org-element but only because it let you.
To fix it, change the mode before you construct the parse tree:
(defun my--get-org-parse-tree (file-path)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file-path)
    (org-mode)
    (org-element-parse-buffer)))

But you might want to report this to the mailing list: org-element-parse-buffer should probably check the mode before going off the deep end.

Thank you, it worked! I also reported this to the mailing list as they may give further information about this behavior

The thread can be found here. Nice report BTW!
